# Is the study of triphthongs a must to master English phonology?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, phonemes, triphthongs

Most universities in India are teaching  only  pure vowels (monophthongs), and  diphthongs. Now  we find  triphthongs. ...

Is  the study  of triphthongs a must to  master the phonology  of   English? Does the study  of  triphthongs  help  a long way in the advanced stages?

I think the study  of triphthongs not  necessary for  those who are not  very advanced  in phonetics.

Comment: No. It is not essential to "study" anything to become a master of phonology: it is enough to hear and reproduce.

Comment: You do not even need to be able to hear of produce any sounds to study phonology: that is what phonetics is about. You *do* need to study phonological systems.

Comment: I have to assume the question is more related to TEFL (or LEFL?) than to linguistics. I have a hard time imagining a situation where "the study of tripthongs may be difficult for those who are not very advanced in phonetics" if it's about a linguistics class.

Comment: I think it is meant for linguistics.You have commented after answering my question.The answer is more useful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By "triphthongs" I assume you're referring to /eɪə, əʊə, aɪə, aʊə, ɔɪə/ found (or posited) in words like in *layer, lower, fire, hour, lawyer* for Standard Southern British English (or Received Pronunciation or BBC English or whatever you want to call it). And by "to master the phonology of English" I assume you're referring to acquisition of the phonology of English as a second/foreign language, not the study of it. And I'm also going to assume the accent model as a target for acquisition being talked about here is one based on what has traditionally been referred to by the names I mentioned above (SSB/RP/BBC), because if your model is based on American English triphthongs are most likely irrelevant.

If these assumptions are true, the answer I'd say is no. First of all, not all accounts of the English vowel system accept that it has triphthongs. Out of the three major pronouncing dictionaries, two (*Longman Pronunciation Dictionary* and *Routledge Dictionary of Pronunciation for Current English*) do not posit triphthongs, transcribing *layer, fire*, etc. as (prototypically) disyllabic and thus as rhymes with *player, liar*, etc. This is because it is very difficult, if not impossible, to determine whether /eɪə/ etc. in certain words are one syllable or two. Some who support the triphthong analysis point to the fact these sequences of vowels often undergo a process called *smoothing*—whereby the vowel in the middle is dropped, resulting in a diphthong or even a monophthong, so that *fire* is pronounced as [faə] or [faː] (similar or identical to *far*)—or argue that monomorphemic words like *layer/hour/fire* are pronounced more quickly and undergo smoothing more often than words like *player/lower/liar*, but the problem is that smoothing does occur in the latter words too and even across word boundaries. I see no reason to try to pronounce *layer, hour, fire*, etc. any differently from *player, lower, liar*, etc. If one wants to sound more like native speakers of SSB/RP/BBC, one should master smoothing (in both groups of words).